# Adding other angular module instances as dependenies

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm pretty new to Angular, could some one please help me in resolving my basic query?

I have the below code:

```
var a = angular.module('myApp', [
'ui.router',
'moduleName1',
'moduleName2'
]).config(...........)
```

Is it possible to separate the dependency array into an isolated file and refer it like below:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
../fileName.js
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

include your js file before angular module declared

```
<script src="myFile.js"></script>
```

Your myFile.js content is

```
var myArray = ['ui.router', 'moduleName1', 'moduleName2'];
```

and you angular app declaration is:

```
angular.module('myApp',
  myArray)
```

Comment: Import the file before loading the main module

Comment: can you provide an example or links?